# Silent client registration for Subscription Management Tool (SMT)

Tags: suse, silent-installer, sles

In the documentation for the Subscription Management Tool (SMT) for Suse repository management, there are [4 ways](https://www.suse.com/documentation/smt11/book_yep/data/smt_client.html) to register a client with the SMT server.

One of these is by running the clientSetup4SMT.sh script. The documentation does not explain any way to perform a silent installation using this script, but is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source of the clientSetup4SMT.sh script the following line of documentation can be found:

```
Usage: $0 --host <hostname of the SMT server> [--fingerprint <fingerprint of server cert>] [--yes]
```

The two options `--fingerprint` and `--yes` are the options we need.

`--fingerprint` is the CA certificate fingerprint. The CA certificate can be found on the SMT server at `http://FQDN/smt.crt` ([FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)). Alternatively it can be accessed at `/srv/www/htdocs/smt.crt`.

Getting the fingerprint from the server is most easily done by deliberately specifying an invalid fingerprint in the script's `--fingerprint` option:

```
clientSetup4SMT.sh --host <hostname of the SMT server> --fingerprint 'somestring' --yes
```

This will return:

```
Server fingerprint: <actual server fingerprint> and given fingerprint:  <wrong server fingerprint> do not match, not accepting cert. Abort.
```

Copy the server fingerprint and paste it into the command as so:

```
clientSetup4SMT.sh --host <hostname of the SMT server> --fingerprint '<actual server fingerprint>' --yes
```

The above command will run silently.

Answer (score 0):

Just rem out the bits that ask for input etc in the .sh script itself...